# How to install an app named Albert?

Tags: software-installation, applications, software-recommendation

I heard about this app today known as **Albert** which is an alternative to Spotlight for Linux. I watched a video on YouTube to see how to install the app but when I tried installing the app it said "*can't find that package*".
I used the following command lines to install the app:-

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install albert`

Also, I was wondering if it's any better to install such an app on my system and if yes, is there any better alternative for Albert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I also couldn't make Albert work and also learned that it doesn't have nearly as much features as on macOS.</s>

**I finally figured out how to make Albert work.**

1. Remove Albert - only if you already tried installing Albert (First startup of Albert crashed on my system and broke the install)

`killall albert`

`sudo apt-get remove albert`

`sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/albert`

`sudo rm -rf /usr/share/albert`

`sudo rm -rf /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.cache/albert`

`sudo rm -rf /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.config/albert`

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list`

`sudo apt-key del E192A257`

`sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update`

2. Download key and add repository

`curl https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key | sudo apt-key add -`

`sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list"`

`sudo apt-get update`

3. Install Albert

`sudo apt-get install albert`

**Note:**

- You manually have to activate Alberts features in the settings (like file search)
- For troubeshooting I recommend starting albert first time from terminal by just typing "albert". Then you can see potential error messages.

Resources:

https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/installing/#importing-the-keyfile

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/gi8edf/how_to_install_a_spotlight_like_search_launcher/fqd81te/

---

Best alternative from my point of view is **uLauncher** combined with the extension "File Search" using fd.

### Installation Steps for uLauncher

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:agornostal/ulauncher`

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install ulauncher`

### Installations Steps for File Search

**Download & Installation of fd**

- Go to https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/releases and download the appropriate package for your system. If you're unsure which package to choose, paste the following in the terminal: `uname -a`
- It should give you something like e.g.: `x86_64`
- Then download the matching .deb package, e.g.: `fd_8.0.0_amd64.deb`
- Change to "Downloads" dir with: `cd && cd Downloads`
- Install .deb package with: `sudo dpkg -i fd_8.0.0_amd64.deb`

**Configuration of fd**

- Configure alias for fd to make it work properly: `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`
- Move to the bottom of the file with the arrow key and paste:

`# fd search alias used by ulauncher`

`alias fd=fdfind`

- Save and exit file with Keys "CTRL+X" then "Y" then "Enter"

**Download & Installation of "File Search" uLauncher Extension**

- Then execute uLauncher from installed apps.
- Click the settings button on the right of the small search window.
- Navigate to extensions tab and click "Add extension".
- Paste following link: https://github.com/brpaz/ulauncher-file-search

**Usage of File Search with uLauncher**

Now you can type in uLauncher "fd SEARCHPHRASE" to find dirs/files or "ff SEARCHPHRASE" for files only. For apps you can directly start typing the name without any keyword.

Comment: It worked but I didn't like it that much. But thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) I updated my answer with instructions how to install albert since I finally made it work. You can check this out, if it suits you more.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the source you're referring to. There's no package for ubuntu 18.04 and up. It havn't been updated in 3 years. So you have to find other means to try Albert.

Comment: Okay. Can you suggest any other such app?

Comment: I don't use it myself,, only synapse briefly. It's in the appcenter.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the official page.

> https://albertlauncher.github.io/

---

I found packages support up to xUbuntu 20.04, also can be gotten from repository.

> https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert

[image]

It is found in the following page with introduction and setup guide.

> Albert is a good Spotlight alternative for Linux April 26, 2019 - by
>   John Been
>   https://www.reallinuxuser.com/albert-is-a-good-spotlight-alternative-for-linux/

I miss Spotlight from Mac, too.